# C++: Overloading double [] operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have multidimensional array in my class

```
class Matrix {
    double **matrix;

    Matrix(int m, int n) : n(n), m(m) {
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {

            matrix[y] = new double[m];
            for (int x = 0; x < m; x++) {
                matrix[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }

    }
...
}
```

Now I want to create getter which works as:

```
Matrix matrix(5,5);
cout << matrix[3][3];
```

I'm looking for any idea how to do it in any c++ standard.

**Pseudocode:**

```
double operator[][](int a, int b){
...
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: In `matrix[1][2]`, `[1]` operates on `matrix` and `[2]` operates on `matrix[1]`. `[1][2]` is not a single operator. You need to give `matrix[1]` a type.

Comment: you can make `Matrix::operator[]` return a proxy that also has an `operator[]`. I am pretty sure that there are dupes if you search carefully

Comment: ^^ or someone else finds it for you